# C# Linq .ToDictionary() Key Already Exists

Tags: c#, regex, linq, dictionary, ini

**Final Edit: I was able to locate the duplicate field in the ini file. Thanks for your help everyone!**

I'm using a regular expression to parse an ini file and LINQ to store it in a Dictionary:

> **Sample Data:**
>   [WindowSettings]
>   Window X Pos='0'
>   Window Y Pos='0'
>   Window Maximized='false'
>   Window Name='Jabberwocky'
>   
>   [Logging]
>   Directory='C:\Rosetta Stone\Logs'

**EDIT: Here is the file actually causing the problem: http://pastebin.com/mQSrkrcP**

**EDIT2: I've narrowed it down to being caused by the last section in the file: [list_first_nonprintable]**

For some reason one of the files that I'm parsing with this is throwing this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Is there any way for me to either find out which key is causing the problem (so I can fix the file), or to just skip the key that's causing this and continue parsing?

Here is the code:

```
try
{
    // Read content of ini file.
    string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(project);

    // Create regular expression to parse ini file.
    string pattern = @"^((?:\[)(?<Section>[^\]]*)(?:\])(?:[\r\n]{0,}|\Z))((?!\[)(?<Key>[^=]*?)(?:=)(?<Value>[^\r\n]*)(?:[\r\n]{0,4}))*";
    //pattern = @"
    //^                           # Beginning of the line
    //((?:\[)                     # Section Start
    //     (?<Section>[^\]]*)     # Actual Section text into Section Group
    // (?:\])                     # Section End then EOL/EOB
    // (?:[\r\n]{0,}|\Z))         # Match but don't capture the CRLF or EOB
    // (                          # Begin capture groups (Key Value Pairs)
    //  (?!\[)                    # Stop capture groups if a [ is found; new section
    //  (?<Key>[^=]*?)            # Any text before the =, matched few as possible
    //  (?:=)                     # Get the = now
    //  (?<Value>[^\r\n]*)        # Get everything that is not an Line Changes
    //  (?:[\r\n]{0,4})           # MBDC \r\n
    //  )*                        # End Capture groups";

    // Parse each file into a Dictionary.
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> iniFile
                    = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)
                       select new
                       {
                           Section = m.Groups["Section"].Value,

                           kvps = (from cpKey in m.Groups["Key"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select((a, i) => new { a.Value, i })
                                   join cpValue in m.Groups["Value"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select((b, i) => new { b.Value, i }) on cpKey.i equals cpValue.i
                                   select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(cpKey.Value, cpValue.Value)).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)

                       }).ToDictionary(itm => itm.Section, itm => itm.kvps);

    return iniFile;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug the results you're getting from your regular expression?  It's producing the same key twice.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this or if it's possible. When I add a breakpoint on the LINQ statement it just highlights the entire thing and goes right to the exception after it runs.

Comment: @TonyTrozzo to a `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary`, go through the lookup, and check which keys appear more than once. I'm nearly certain that the key that appears multiple times is going to be an empty string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I bet you're right, in which case he could probably add a Where() clause to clean that out...

Comment: When I run your code against the sample data, everything seems to work fine.  Have you checked your ini file to make sure that it doesn't have a section declared more than once?

Comment: @RichMcCollister You're correct, the sample data does work. Here is the file actually causing the problem: http://pastebin.com/mQSrkrcP I checked and was unable to find any duplicate sections.

Comment: Tony,  I ran a query against your data.  You do have a duplicate under the list_first_nonprintable section.  field26 was used twice.  On pastbin, line 491 and line 496.  I'm guessing that the second is a mistype and should be field27.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This just means that when you convert to a Dictionary --

```
.ToDictionary(itm => itm.Section, itm => itm.kvps);
```

-- there are multiple keys (itm.Section).  You can use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) instead, which is kind of like a dictionary but allows multiple keys.

**Edit**

There are a couple of ways to call *ToLookup*.  The simplest is to specify the key selector:

```
var lookup = 
   // ...
.ToLookup(itm => itm.Section);
```

This should provide a lookup where the key is of type **Group**.  Getting a lookup value should then return an IEnumerable, where T is the anonymous type:

```
Group g = null;
// TODO get group
var lookupvalues = lookup[g];
```

If the .NET compiler doesn't like this (sometimes it seems to have trouble figuring out what the various types should be), you can also specify an element selector, for example:

```
ILookup<string, KeyValuePair<string,string>> lookup = 
    // ...
.ToLookup(
    itm => itm.Section.Value,    // key selector
    itm => itm.kvps              // element selector
);
```

Comment: He could then use LinqPad and call .Dump() to look at the data.

Comment: @dbaseman I'm having trouble converting this Dictionary to a Lookup. Are the arguments to it different than itm.Section and itm.kvps?

Comment: @TonyTrozzo I put more details into the answer, hopefully that provides more clarity.  It could be that the compiler is having trouble due to the presence of the anonymous type.  In those cases, the compiler suggestion is to try specifying the type parameters explicitly.

Comment: Appreciate all the help. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a word of advice to anyone following these solutions: Duplicate keys might mean duplicate values; this means you have discriminate between the duplicate values. This could be as simple as picking the first or last one found, in either case some values are being thrown out.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own ToDictionary method that doesn't break with duplicate keys easy enough.

```
public static Dictionary<K,V> ToDictionary<TSource, K, V>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, K> keySelector, 
    Funct<TSource, V> valueSelector)
{
  //TODO validate inputs for null arguments.

  Dictionary<K,V> output = new Dictionary<K,V>();
  foreach(TSource item in source)
  {
    //overwrites previous values
    output[keySelector(item)] = valueSelector(item); 

    //ignores future duplicates, comment above and 
    //uncomment below to change behavior
    //K key = keySelector(item);
    //if(!output.ContainsKey(key))
    //{
      //output.Add(key, valueSelector(item));
    //}
  }

  return output;
}
```

I assume that you could figure out how to implement the additional overloads (without value the selector).

Comment: I think you mean: if(!output.ContainsKey(key))

Comment: @zumalifeguard Nope, there's no need.  The indexer overwrites existing values that are there, unlike `Add`.

Comment: Servy, I wasn't clear.   I am talking about the commented out section.   What you have right now is "if(!output.ContainsKey(item))".  I'm saying that the parameter shouldn't be "item", but "key".  If you uncomment out that code, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tuple` to pass multiple keys. Check sample code below:

```
.ToDictionary(k => new Tuple<string,string>(k.key1,k.key2), v => v.value)
```

Comment: you can use this to prepare dictionary based on multiple key's e.g var employees=entities.Employee.select(e=>e.FirstName,e.Lastname,e.Empid)..ToDictionary(k => new Tuple<string,string>(k.FirstName,k.LastName), v => v.EmpId); this will give you a dictionary based on composite key(FirstName,LastName) and value as empid. key is always unique in dictionary so you can filter based on composite key.

Comment: I just asked that because the answer would in turn improve your answer. Why don't you [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35198142/edit) and incorporate the comment to improve helpfulness?