# Linq query to dictionary throws System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query that I am using to query a datatable and populate a dictionary, but it keeps throwing the error:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

I am new to LINQ and cannot figure out the proper way to write this.

**Can someone please assist?**

```
var neworderGroupDict = (from m in KMVData.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                           datakey = m.Field<string>("OrderNumber"),
                           datavalue = m.Field<int>("OrderGroup")
                         }).Distinct().ToDictionary(n => n.datakey, n => n.datavalue);
```

Comment: Is it possible you have two records with the same order number but different order groups?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10625879/371298

Comment: No, the order number is distinct to the group.

Answer (score 11):

That means your data key (in this case combination of `OrderNumber` and `OrderGroup`) is not unique. Happens because `.Distinct()` wont filter duplicates without `IEqualityComparer` for your type.

**Edit:**

One way of fixing that and preserving all datavalues for `OrderNumber` is first grouping by and then converting it to dictionary:

```
var neworderGroupDict = (from m in KMVData.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             datakey = m.Field<string>("OrderNumber"),
                             datavalue = m.Field<int>("OrderGroup")
                         }).GroupBy(x => x.datakey)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: This is the reason why it is not working, but not a solution for his problem :p

Answer (score 0):

Try `DistinctBy` of [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).
Then you can use `ToDictionary` without any problems.